# Is using prime number good for determining the "on" / "true" values for a set of conditions?

Tags: primes

I want to check if a list contains an element. Now instead of traversing the list every single time, I want to find a quick solution. Suppose there are a list of rules r1,r2,r3,r4,r5. Each with an id 3,5,7,11,13(all prime numbers) for users. I am getting different user ids with a list of their specific rules/characteristics .

I have different groupings of rules for bucketing users according to certain conditions. For ex. group1 = r1 & r2 , group2 = r3 , group3 = r3,r4 & r5 ; here groups serve as buckets of users with a combination of certain rules/characteristics

Now If a user u1 satisfies rules/charactersitics r1,r2 &r3 he should fall in group1 & group2

And If a user u2 satisfies rules/charactersitics  r3,r4,r5 he should fall in group2 & group3

According to my solution  I will find out the product of the rule ids which are prime numbers for a user. Therefore for u1 it will be r1 * r2 * r3 = 3*5*7 = 105 . I will do this calculation only once & then find out the product of the rule ids per group.

```
group1 -> r1 * r2 = 3*5 = 15
group2 -> r3 = 7
group3 -> r3*r4*r5 = 7*11*13 = 1001
```

I can also do the above calculation(for finding group product) at the time of group creation to avoid traversing the rule ids in groups every time.

Now for the main part, I will check

for all groups {
if  uid rule product % group product ==0
then uid lies in that group

}

Now since I am using only prime numbers, If a rule id is present in a group but not in a user's rules then its **uid rule product % group product** can never be zero.

I hope my question is not too vague. Waiting to listen from people who have done something like that or think this could work.

Comment: While it "would" work, as long as primes `x*y*z..` never exceeded the size of the integer/mask, it is definitely *not* the common approach for such a task.. (using primes leaves many "gaps" and is rather inefficient encoding of such)

Answer (score 2):

found your question  by walking around : .
you which to distinguish several rules: using prime would work but cost a lot. Simplest way is to add power of 2: 1+2+4+8 etc. (yes binary ! ) To find if a rule or a set is inside do an AND: if result = question, ok.
This way with 32 bits: 32 rules .with prime 2 X 3 X 5 X 7 × 11 X 13 X 17 (7rules only) already takes more than 32bits. Quite simple:a new rule multiply by 2 in first case, otherwise multiply by next (growing) prime. could quickly go out of range.

hth